# Why can't the compiler deduce to this function template?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, std-function, function-signature

We have a function that takes a function object as parameter. There are two overloads of the function, which differ in the function signature.

```
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
void foo(std::function<void(T)> bar)
{

}

template <typename T>
void foo(std::function<void(int, T)> bar)
{

}

int main()
{
    foo([](float number) {

    });
    return 0;
}
```

However, this code doesn't compile.

```
error C2784: 'void foo(std::function<void(int,T)>)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::function<void(int,T)>' from 'main::<lambda_2b4e4413ec419a4ac179a0b64ebde221>' : see declaration of 'foo'
error C2784: 'void foo(std::function<void(T)>)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::function<void(T)>' from 'main::<lambda_2b4e4413ec419a4ac179a0b64ebde221>' : see declaration of 'foo'
```

I think there is a problem with both the template itself and the overload. How can I provide two functions that match the above signatures?

Comment: lambda is not derived from std::function

Comment: Template type deduction tries to find types for `T`, such that `std::function<void(int, T)>`, or `std::function<void(T)>` respectively, becomes *equal* to the type of the argument `[](float){}`. There is no such `T` that makes the type of the lambda equal to some `std::function<..>` type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lambdas in C++ are instances of an anonymous class specifically created for each lambda object, this means that two lambdas with the same code are actually *different* objects.

This also means that you can't pass lambdas around without using a template because there's no lambda type. Lambda is neither `std::function` ( and is not derived from it) nor a function pointer. They are unique types implementing application operator, i.e `operator()`.

You can do it using static_cast operator

```
template <typename T>
void foo(std::function<void(T)> bar)
{
}

foo( static_cast< std::function<void(float)> >( [](float number){}));
//or
foo( std::function<void(float)>{ [](float){} } );
```

Comment: The `static_cast`, btw, can even be left out: `foo( std::function<void(float)>{ [](float){} } );` but that doesn't answer the OP's question, I guess.

Comment: well, once it is true it is still better to use static_cast to signal the harshness of cast

Answer (score 1):

The reason is apparently one of the side effects of having each lambda expression to be have its own type.

This means for example that you cannot declare a lambda parameter, or a pointer to a lambda. It also means that you cannot use lambdas when type deduction is needed (e.g. for template instantiation).

The solution is to wrap lambdas into `std::function<...>` objects as soon as possible because those have a type that can be specified and matched in templates.

For example you cannot have a function that returns a lambda, or store a lambda in a member... but you can return an `std::function` or store `std::function` into members.

In the specific your code works with

```
foo(std::function<void(float)>([](float number){});
```

Comment: *"It also means that you cannot use lambdas when type deduction is needed"* Too general. You cannot deduce the return type of a lambda directly via "pattern matching" etc. You can do what the OP wants via SFINAE. *"For example you cannot have a function that returns a lambda"* We have C++14 now, with return type deduction for ordinary functions. *"or store a lambda in a member."* This is always possible by deducing the type of the lambda, and using a class template. What you *cannot* do, (IMHO to be more precise), is *name* the type of the lambda directly.